# What program(s) is stored in a small partition on my hard drive with flags `bios_grub`?

Tags: boot, partition, grub, boot-loader, bios

My old laptop uses BIOS. It came with Windows installed, and later I installed Ubuntu by overwriting Windows.

What program(s) is stored in a small partition on my hard drive with flags `bios_grub`, shown by `parted`?  It can't store BIOS, because BIOS is stored in ROM, not in disk. It can't store what is stored in MBR or GPT, because MBR and GPT are stored in disk but not in any partition.

What is the purpose of the partition?
Is the partition used when booting Ubuntu?  Or was it used only when Windows was installed on the laptop?

When booting Ubuntu, BIOS loads the bootloader program form the MBR of a boot disk, which in turn loads the remaining boot loader program from the boot block of a boot partition. Is the small partition with flag `bios_grub`  involved in booting OS process in any way?

Thanks.

```
$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for t: 
Model: ATA ST1000LM014-1EJ1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      116GB   716GB   600GB   ext4
 3      716GB   1000GB  284GB   ext4
```

Comment: read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition). It basically contains the `grub` bootloader on a GPT partitioned disk, which would've otherwise fit on the first 2-63 or 2-2048 unused sectors if a DOS partitioning scheme were used.

Comment: that's why `sfdisk -d` is better than `sfdisk -l` or  `parted -l` -- it's so much easier for everybody when unambiguous IDs are used instead of made-up confusing names like `bios_grub` or `BIOS boot`.

Comment: See also this Ubuntu help page, [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: @mosvy Thanks.  "made-up confusing names like bios_grub or BIOS boot". The name of the column is called "Flags" not "Names"

Comment: And that's exactly the problem I was talking about -- **there's no `bios_grub` partition flag in the GPT**. It's something completely made up by `parted`. Please read the GPT wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), there's no point in copy pasting stuff from there here.

Comment: All partitions are identified by GUIDs (a kind of unique names). One such GUID is identifying the "legacy bios" grub partition. `parted` is "abstracting" the GUID into a "flag". That's only making everything a lot more confusing than it really is.

Comment: @mosvy thanks. I created https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502145/installation-and-booting-scenarios-for-combinations-of-boot-sector-gpt-or-mbr after following your comment.